# Navigating to a specific page based on radio button checked in Angular

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular10

I'm trying to make a simple login app, for both normal users and the admin. I made a working login function, but I want the user to choose whether he's a normal user or an admin. I want to use radio buttons for it. Based on the radio button clicked, after logging in, I want the user to navigate to the respective page. So if the user checked the "user" radio button, I want him to go to the page specifically for users, and if the user checked "admin" radio button, I want him to navigate to the page specifically for admins after logging in.

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ6ad.png)

This is a piece of code where the logging in is happening, and the user gets navigated to home for now after loggin in.

```
    if(this.checkCredentials(signInData)) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
      return true;
    }
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    return false;
  }
```

This is my HTML code where my radio buttons are

```
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="user" name="usertype" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" ng-model="userischecked"checked required>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="admin">User</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="admin" name="usertype" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="admin">Admin</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
```

The loggin in happens in the authentication service and the radio buttons are in the login component HTML file, if that helps.

EDIT: I'm attaching my whole HTML code:

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-signin"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signInForm)" #signInForm="ngForm">
                <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                
                <label for="inputID" class="sr-only">ID</label>
                <input type="id" id="inputID" name="id" class="form-control" 
                placeholder="ID" required autofocus ngModel>
                
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Password" required ngModel>
                
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

                <div class="d-block my-3">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="user" name="usertype" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" ng-model="userischecked"checked required>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="admin">User</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="admin" name="usertype" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="admin">Admin</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Code

```
 <label id="example-radio-group-label">Select your role</label>
 <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" class="example-radiogroup" [(ngModel)]="selectedRole">
 <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let role of rolesAvailable" [value]="role">
{{role}}
</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your role is: {{selectedRole}}</div>
```

TS code

```
selectedRole: string;
rolesAvailable: string[] = ['Admin', 'User'];

login(){
 console.log(this.selectedRole)  //Will give you the role selected;
 if(this.selectedRole=="Admin"){
    this.router.navigate(['admin'])
 }
 else if(this.selectedRole=="User"){
   this.router.navigate(['user'])
 }
}
```

[Check this](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview)

Code without material HTML

```
<input type="radio" value="Admin" [(ngModel)]="selectedRole">Admin
<input type="radio" value="User" [(ngModel)]="selectedRole">User
```

Comment: Am I supposed to overwrite my radio button HTML code with yours? Because when I do, my page becomes completely blank. I'll attach my whole HTML code in the question.

Comment: ng add @angular/material -To add material in your project ||
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio'; - Import this in app.module

|| At the bottom there is code without material, that should work for you